# File get contents returns false

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I'm trying to have users verify that they own the domain. So I generated a file and have them upload it to their site. So I then have to verify it, so what I do is

```
file_get_contents($url.'/'.$token.'.html');
```

All this returns is

```
bool(false)
```

Here's more of the code

```
$url = $_POST['url'];

//Get site info
$gin = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM verify WHERE url = :url");
$gin->bindValue(':url', $url);
$gin->execute();

//Get token
$t = $gin->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$token = $t['token'];
$url = $t['url'];


//Get content
var_dump(file_get_contents($url.'/'.$token.'.html'));
```

I have 3 columns in the table `token`, which is the string in the file. `url` which is the url obviously, its in `example.com` format. And a verified column which is either `1` or `0`. Any ideas?

Comment: Any debugging? `example.com` is not an URL, subsquently should result in a warning, as would a disabled allow_url_fopen.

Comment: what happens if you try and view that path in your browser?

Comment: I've tried `http` also but that didn't work @thescientist

Comment: It takes me to the location @thescientist

Comment: What does display `echo  $url.'/'.$token.'.html';` ?

Comment: `example.com/55F7HnQzec171f9nwWew2ya7EABMSNZYTE5.html`. Then I'd visit it and see the string @Isaac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add http:// before $url and put a valid url. It will work

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('http://'.$url.'/'.$token.'.html')); // With a valid URL
```

Comment: Is the url that you use is accessible from a browser ? Or does it return a 404

Comment: Can I have an example of valid url that you used with file_get_contents wich return you false ?

Answer (score 5):

Based on my experience with fetching third-party content from more than 1 million domain names, I would not recommend you to use `file_get_contents()` because this PHP function cannot handle page redirects, site that requires a valid user-agent etc. The issue you are experiencing might be specific to a certain domain names only. A better approach to your problem is to use curl.

```
    function download_content($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Firefox 32.0");
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$returned_content = download_content('http://stackoverflow.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enable `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, then you will probably see that the use of HTTP URLs are disallowed due to an [ini setting](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen).

Warning: you are possibly opening a hole by allowing arbitrary prefixes in `file_get_contents`. Try to use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse-url) to validate that you actually have a HTTP URL. Then you should probably consider using cURL and disable external redirects (otherwise one could pass a URL such as `http://bit.ly/something#` and still pass your tests).